# Simulate a person who is working in a quarry with classes

Tags: c#, object-oriented, delegates, properties

I build my first "bigger" program with classes. Does this look good? Or do you see something, which I could do better?
Do you think I could use a delegate for changing the stones to money here? And how to do this?

```
using System;

// collect stones
// if 20 stones collected --> event --> change stones for money

namespace FunInTheQuarry
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Quarry quarry = new Quarry();
            Person person1 = new Person();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
                person1.Work();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} stones in the quarry.", Quarry.stone);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Quarry
    {
        public static int stone { get; set; }

        public Quarry()
        {
            stone = 10000;
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int stone;
        public int money;

        public Person()
        {
            stone = 0;
            money = 0;
        }

        public void Work()
        {
            stone += 1;
            Quarry.stone -= 1;
            if (this.stone >= 20)
            {
                ChangeStonesToMoney(ref this.stone, ref this.money);
            }
        }

        public void ChangeStonesToMoney(ref int stone, ref int money)
        {
            stone -= 20;
            money += 1;
            Console.WriteLine("One Person has now {0} dollar.", this.money);
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: this is my revised work.

http://pastebin.com/99gRrUqv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before worrying about `delegates`, there are some very basic notions we should review! :)

Never, **ever** <strike>getting back together</strike> expose your fields. They should be `private`. Use properties like you did in your `Quarry` class instead.
This pattern is called [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) and is an important practice in the software development process.

In general, an instance (like `new Quarry()`) shouldn't deal with `static` fields. Why is that? Imagine the following scenario where you have 2 quarries.

```
Quarry quarry = new Quarry();
quarry.stone -= 100; //Somebody's been working hard
Quarry quarry2 = new Quarry();
Console.WriteLine(quarry.stone);
```

What is printed? Is it `9900`? Nope, because your instance constructor resets the `static` field. The `stone` field shouldn't be static. Each `Quarry` should have its own number of stones. Maybe the number of stones could be customized with a parameter in the constructor?

```
public class Quarry
{
    public int Stones { get; set; }

    public Quarry(int stones)
    {
        Stones = stones;
    }
}
```

This way each of your `Quarry` is independant.

Next problem, there is no relation between your `Person` and your `Quarry`. This is bad. A `Person` works in a `Quarry` (in your example, we'll keep it simple), but in your code, we don't see this relation. To keep it simple, we'll say that a `Person` `Works` with a `Quarry`. What does it mean? It means that the `Work` method should receive a `Quarry` parameter.

```
public class Person
{
    public int stone;
    public int money;

    public Person()
    {
        stone = 0;
        money = 0;
    }

    public void Work(Quarry quarry)
    {
        stone += 1;
        quarry.Stones -= 1;
        if (this.stone >= 20)
        {
            ChangeStonesToMoney(ref this.stone, ref this.money);
        }
    }

    public void ChangeStonesToMoney(ref int stone, ref int money)
    {
        stone -= 20;
        money += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("One Person has now {0} dollar.", this.money);
    }
}
```

Notice that `stones` isn't the best variable name you can use. Perhaps `workedStones` would be better. Or something like this.

Also, you use `Thread.Sleep(300);` in your main loop, but I assume that it's the person's work that takes 300 milliseconds (damn those persons are fast!). So maybe the sleep should be in the `Work` method. Using `Thread.Sleep()` is unorthodox and is usually not recommended, but for your example I get why you're using it! :)

I noticed you were using `ref`. That's bad. I mean, you used it in a "good" scenario, as you want to modify an `int` by reference, but you don't need to do this and you shouldn't include `ref` everywhere just for the kick of it.

You already have access to `stone` and `money`, so why pass them as parameter?

```
public void Work()
{
    stone += 1;
    Quarry.stone -= 1;
    if (this.stone >= 20)
    {
        ChangeStonesToMoney();
    }
}

public void ChangeStonesToMoney()
{
    stone -= 20;
    money += 1;
    Console.WriteLine("One Person has now {0} dollar.", this.money);
}
```

Now, I don't have time to go for a longer review, but I suggest you think about the following points :

- Why is the `Person` class responsible for knowing how many stones are worth a dollar? Shouldn't another class be responsible for this?
- Shouldn't a `Quarry` have a list of `Person` that works for it? Instead of having different people work on a quarry once in awhile like it is actually done at the moment.
- <strike>Are these people under the minimum wage?</strike>

Otherwise, there's some good stuff in there, you've done a good job for a first little application :)

Comment: Thank you very much! One question. Why does `ChangeStonesToMoney()` know who the money gets if I have more than one Person.

Comment: @kame I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I think I have to make a better plan about the relation of all my classes and objects.

Comment: @kame I propose you post a follow-up question, this way you'll get other reviews :)

Comment: One of the best explanation I have seen in a longtime. It has helped me understand How to give a good feedback

Comment: @Ramesh well thank you that's very kind :)